# XPath expression can't extract mailto: attribute

Tags: python, regex, xpath

I'm using this XPath for getting the text() that follows mailto:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()
```

Now I want to be able to extract what comes *after* `mailto:` for such attribute:

```
<a href="mailto:info@info.com?subject=hello">here</a>
```

I want to get: `info@info.com?subject=hello`

What XPath should I be using to get the string just after the mailto:?

Edit: seems that the mailto: is being generated using javascript.
      Can scrapy handle such thing?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
 var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
 var addy54802 = '&#105;nf&#111;' + '&#64;';
 addy54802 = addy54802 + 'zl&#97;ng&#111;' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m?s&#117;bj&#101;ct=C&#97;r&#101;&#101;r%20&#97;t%20Zl&#97;ng&#111;';
 var addy_text54802 = 'here';
 document.write('<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy54802 + '\'>');
 document.write(addy_text54802);
 document.write('<\/a>');
 //-->\n </script>
```

Solution: I think I should be using Selenium for javascript.

Comment: Why can't you just get that part after you get whole href, just take part after mailto from string

Comment: The first problem is: How do you get the *value* of an attribute? I don't know so I delete my wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below sample XML, for fetching string after `mailto:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>
    <a href="mailto:info@info.com?subject=hello">here</a>
</div>
```

you can use below xpath expression

```
substring-after(/div/a/@href,'mailto:')
```

it returns `info@info.com?subject=hello`

***In your case xpath will look like:***

```
substring-after(//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/@href,'mailto:')
```

Comment: This did the trick, do you know how to get rid of ? and what comes after it - just to have the plain email without the subject (if any)

Comment: This only returns the first result, I need to get all results.

Answer (score 0):

```
for $a in //a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]
    return substring-after(normalize-space($a/@href),'mailto:')
```

**UPDATE**

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/substring-after(normalize-space(./@href),'mailto:')
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this in one line using xpath?

Comment: This does not work.
 Invalid XPath: //a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/substring-after(normalize-space(./@href),'mailto:')

Comment: I try in in scrapy shell using the expression you provided.
did you check it?

Comment: @user1537701: Try this ``hxs.select('//a[contains(@href, "href")]/@href').re(r'mailto:\s*(.*)')``.